# How to share methods documentation within class with jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

My class has methods with same arguments description.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
var Person = function (){};

Person.prototype = {

  /**
   * @param {!string} [arg] - words
   */
  whisper: function(arg){
      console.log(arg.toLowerCase());
  },

  /**
   * @param {!string} [arg] - words
   */
  shout: function(arg){
      console.log(arg.toUpperCase());
  },
};
```

How to share method documentation within class?

Is it possible to not only share methods documentation, but mix it with inline method description? Example: each method will have different @return type.

Comment: That's a pretty good sign that the parameter should be moved to a ctor parameter instead.

Comment: Good point. Now I use described with jsdoc argument of special `PersonWords` type for both methods.